# Styled Components & React: Click event

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to create an onClick for a Styled Components Component, but it is not working. It is not logging `hello` in the console.

```
<Component onClick={this.handleClick} />
```

The handleClick:

```
handleClick(e) {
    console.log("hello");
}
```

This is also in the constructor:

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
```

The component:

```
const Component = styled.span`
    /* Regular CSS */
    ${css};
`;
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The component is nested in a Button component. When I add the onClick to the Button Component `hello` is shown in the console. However I want the child to have this function not the parent.

EDIT 2:

Ok so when I change the CSS it works. I have no idea why. This is my css:

```
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        display: block;
        z-index: 0;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: inherit;
```

Comment: Share code of `Component`

Comment: The OP @Mose suggested https://codesandbox.io/s/5xrlwz9w6n and me https://codesandbox.io/s/oq7z960x1y ,, both version works.. Check if you are missing something in your code then..

Answer (score 0):

We probably need more code. Anyway the cleanest way to bind is by arrow functions:

```js
handleClick = () => console.log('click')
```

If your Button is INSIDE  you have to use another props as onClick is binded to onClick event.
Try

```js
// In Parent
<Parent action={this.handleClick} />

// In Child
<Child onClick={this.props.action} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your span is rendered with a css value of `display: inline`. If there is no actual content in it to expand, it will be 0 pixels in width, and therefore you are not actually clicking on it.

I ran into the same issues and in Styled Components I couldn't make it work with a forced `display: block`. You should use a clickable item, like `styled.button...`

Answer (score -2):

You might want to try this:

```
handleClick = e => {
  console.log('hello');
}
```

...

```
<Component onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)} />
```

or

```
<Component onClick={this.handleClick.bind(e)}/>
```